# Acquire direction between points along route

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, network-analyst, hydrology, direction

How can I generate a directionality attribute between two points along a route/line?

Currently I am using Network Analyst to determine closest facilities, but I need a direction (upstream/downstream) along the route from incidents to facilities. Below is a visual example. The attribute I am trying to generate would be the direction ("Upstream") along the route you would have to travel to get from A to B. It should be noted that A and B are different features of different feature classes.

I am somewhat new to Network Analyst. Also, I am open to using methods other than Network Analyst.

[image: Example:]

EDIT:
Clarification

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if Network Analyst is the best tool for what you are trying to do.
Perhaps using a [Geometric Network](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geometric-networks/what-are-geometric-networks-.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_BFF935417F2549A98CF0DA60F0078801) would work better\easier since it sounds like you are doing water flow analysis.

Comment: I am open to using methods other than Network Analyst, how could this be done using Geometric Network?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I found was extracting DEM values to each of these points. Then using those values, I created a field calculator statement that essentially was B > A = B is upstream of A.